# What is the default path for OSX system include files when building a C++ application?

Tags: c++, macos

I am building a C++ application at the command line (using `make` with an open-source library (Xerces 2.8)).  One of the files includes an OSX system file,

```
#include <TextUtils.h>
```

When I type `make -n` to determine the command used to compile the given file, there is no include path for the system framework files provided.  Therefore, I assume that on OSX the gcc compiler looks in a default location for system include files.

I would like to know what this location is.  When I search for `TextUtils.h`, I see many versions of the file in different locations, including a few different possible candidates for what might be a default location.

How can I determine the default path the system uses for system include files?

Comment: I had looked at that question and it isn't relevant to my scenario (and my question wasn't answered there) because that question is in regards to Xcode, whereas my question is in regards to running gcc directly at the command line.

Comment: My Apologies, My initial reaction was a possibe a duplicate, Sadly, It wont allow me to remove the `Close`. But I hope this comment here should deter people from voting to close it further.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Executing the following command

```
# echo "" | gcc -xc - -v -E
```

will output the buildin configuration of gcc among which are the default includes.

Comment: Thanks.  This points the way.  However, the relevant result from the above command points to /System/Library/Frameworks, whereas the actual path of the file is /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CarbonCore.framework/Versions/A/Headers.  Can you shed light?

Comment: Can you explain what this does exactly? I see it gives me my default include path, but how do I change it?

Comment: It preprocesses an empty file (provided on stdin by the echo) and shows the commandline for the individual stages of the compiling process. The default is I think coming from a spec file but I do not know much about those. You can atleast ignore the default paths with `-nostdinc`