# How to construct default g++ include path on mac 10.8?

Tags: macos, g++

This post: [What is the default path for OSX system include files when building a C++ application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6715454/what-is-the-default-path-for-osx-system-include-files-when-building-a-c-applic) gives me a command I can run to see what my default g++ include path is:

```
echo "" | gcc - -xc -v -E
```

When I run this, among other things, I get my default include path:

```
#include <...> search starts here:
/Applications/gcc471/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin12.0.0/4.7.1/include
/usr/local/include
/Applications/gcc471/include
/Applications/gcc471/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin12.0.0/4.7.1/include-fixed
/usr/include
/System/Library/Frameworks
/Library/Frameworks
```

However, I have no idea how this path is constructed. How do I change the order of this default path? Note, this is not $PATH (I know how to do export $PATHs in my .profile). Checking /etc/paths led to a help file explaining how $PATH is actually constructed, but I want to know how this different include path (not sure if it has a system name like $INCLUDEPATH) is constructed, and how I can change its order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's kinda *builtin* to `gcc`; see `gcc -dumpspecs`.  [This article](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/SpecsFileHOWTO) shows you how to change all that stuff, however you don't need to change it, you just add to it using the `-I` command line option:

e.g.:

```
$ gcc -I /path/to/my/fave/lib -c file.cpp
```

(you can use multiple `-I` flags on the same command line).